# Cloudformation : Associate PublicIP to EC2 instance among multiple network interfaces with EIPs

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, elastic-ip

**My Setup :**

- Three Network Interfaces
- Two EIPs attached to two network interfaces
- Associating both the EIP to the instance using network interface

**I am using cloudformation and code snippet for this is below**

```
  vSRXEip11:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::EIP'
    Properties:
      Domain: vpc
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: ManagementElasticIP
  vSRXEip12:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::EIP'
    Properties:
      Domain: vpc
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: RevenueDataElasticIP
  AssociateEIP11:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::EIPAssociation'
    Properties:
      AllocationId: !GetAtt
        - vSRXEip11
        - AllocationId
      NetworkInterfaceId: !Ref vSRXInterface11
  AssociateEIP12:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::EIPAssociation'
    Properties:
      AllocationId: !GetAtt
        - vSRXEip12
        - AllocationId
      NetworkInterfaceId: !Ref vSRXInterface12
  VpcvSRXEC2Instance1:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Instance'
    Metadata:
      Comment1: Launch Juniper VSRX1
    Properties:
      InstanceType: !FindInMap
        - vSRXInstance
        - !Ref VSRXType
        - Type
      KeyName: !Ref KeyName
      DisableApiTermination: !If
        - EnableTerm
        - true
        - false
      ImageId: !FindInMap
        - JunipervSRXAMI
        - !Ref 'AWS::Region'
        - byol
#https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-network-iface-embedded.html
      NetworkInterfaces:
        - NetworkInterfaceId: !Ref vSRXInterface11
          DeviceIndex: '0'
        - NetworkInterfaceId: !Ref vSRXInterface12
          DeviceIndex: '1'
        - NetworkInterfaceId: !Ref vSRXInterface13
          DeviceIndex: '2'
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: Juniper VSRX1
    DependsOn: IGW
```

When I deploy above cloudformation template, I see sometimes `vSRXEip11` attached as public IP and sometimes `vSRXEip12`.

**How should I make the public IP address of EC2 instance to either `vSRXEip11` or `vSRXEip12` ?**

I tried with `associatePublicIPAddress` for one of the network interface like below.

```
  VpcvSRXEC2Instance1:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Instance'
    Metadata:
      Comment1: Launch Juniper VSRX1
    Properties:
      InstanceType: !FindInMap
        - vSRXInstance
        - !Ref VSRXType
        - Type
      KeyName: !Ref KeyName
      DisableApiTermination: !If
        - EnableTerm
        - true
        - false
      ImageId: !FindInMap
        - JunipervSRXAMI
        - !Ref 'AWS::Region'
        - byol
#https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-network-iface-embedded.html
      NetworkInterfaces:
        - NetworkInterfaceId: !Ref vSRXInterface11
          DeviceIndex: '0'
          AssociatePublicIPAddress: true
        - NetworkInterfaceId: !Ref vSRXInterface12
          DeviceIndex: '1'
        - NetworkInterfaceId: !Ref vSRXInterface13
          DeviceIndex: '2'
```

But got an error saying `"The associatePublicIPAddress parameter cannot be specified when launching with multiple network interfaces"`

Comment: So only one public IP is working?

Comment: Both the IPs are working fine but sometimes one EIP attaches to public interface and sometimes other one. I have two EIPs.